# Add limit to Content Element

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I setup a website with TYPO3 9x and I inserted a Content Element with this type :

```
Categorized content [menu_categorized_content]
```

The objective is to show the contents that are in a given category.

But I need to limit the number of content records to show only 3 records.

How can I add this function to limit to number of content ?

Comment: You can override the template and handle there a limit. In combination with e.g. the field layout, you can enable your editors to select limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TYPO3 is using the `DatabaseQueryProcessor` to fetch the records from DB.

**Your can find the settings in:**

```
typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/ContentElement/MenuCategorizedContent.typoscript
```

The `DatabaseQueryProcessor` uses the default `.select` syntax from TypoScript, you can find the Docs here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Select.html#comprehensive-example

**You can just add this to your TypoScript:**

```
tt_content.menu_categorized_content.dataProcessing.10.max = 3
```